# How to translate any coordinates to relative div position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I'm trying to use HTML, CSS and Javascript to solve the following issue and still couldn't find a solution:

Lets say I have an outer box div, in which I want to locate an inner box div.
The input I have is:

x coordinate - between 0 and MAX_X_VALUE

y coordinate - between 0 and MAX_Y_VALUE

(x,y) indicates the left upper corner of the inner box.

I want to normalize the x,y coordinates to a corresponding position in
the outer box.
In this way (MAX_X_VALUE, MAX_Y_VALUE) will be translated to the right bottom corner of the outer box.

I tried to use absolute positioning, and use % unit in 'top' and 'left'.
In this way, if I get (MAX_X_VALUE, MAX_Y_VALUE) the inner box will be placed 
outside the outer box.

What is the right way to approach this problem and how can I restrict that
the inner box will stay in the boundaries of the outer box?

Here is a snippet of my code:

**CSS**

```
.outer-box {
  margin-left: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-box {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 6vw;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 5px gray;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
innerBoxElement.style.left = `${Math.floor(x / MAX_X_VALUE* 100)}%`;
innerBoxElement.style.top = `${Math.floor(y / MAX_Y_VALUE* 100)}%`;
outerBoxElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', innerBoxElement);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can call [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on any element to get its absolute position and dimensions relative to the top left corner of the browser window.

Comment: Created a [mre] and managed to find the proper formula: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/67ef1tb9/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!
Just one question - when I try to do getBoundingClientRect()  on the inner box I get only 0 values. Can you assume why?

Comment: Judging by the last line of your code, you are inserting the inner box dynamically? Until an element is part of the DOM (i.e. inserted into your actual document), you can't measure it. In this case, since the box uses `8vw` / `6vw` though, you can use `0.08 * window.innerWidth` to determine its eventual width. Same for its height.

Comment: Great, found the issue.
Thank you very much @ChrisG.